# The issue in the prophecy of 1914

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, prophecy, chronology

I was reading [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eschatology_of_Jehovah%27s_Witnesses#:%7E:text=Jehovah%27s%20Witnesses%20assert%20that%20Jerusalem,years%20after%20October%20607%20BC.) Wikipedia article and I reached this part:

> Jehovah's Witnesses assert that Jerusalem was destroyed by the Babylonians in 607 BC and completely uninhabited for exactly seventy years. This date is critical to their selection of October 1914 for the arrival of Christ in kingly power—2520 years after October 607 BC.

2520 years after October 607 BC was October 1913. Why did they say it would be 1914?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have failed to account for the fact that there was no zero year.  1 BC was immediately followed by AD 1.  That will correct your math.

That said, I in no wise endorse this 2520-year prophetic application.

Comment: Correct    https://www.jw.org/en/library/books/bible-teach/1914-significant-year-bible-prophecy/